# How to get status of like in sharepoint rest api query

Tags: 2013, rest

I have a photo list in sharepoint. When the individual items are viewed I make a rest api call and find the title and number of likes for that individual item.

```
http://sharepointsite.com/sites/sitename/pun/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List%20Name')/items?$select=Title,LikesCount
```

Now how can I get the status of Like(ie like/unlike) using the api query?

I could not find any column name in the list which stores the status of like for that particular user

Comment: any help from my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is column named `LikedBy` which stores the users who have liked this item.

`LikedBy` is lookup column (People or Group). So you have to `$expand` this column in your query like following

```
http://sharepointsite.com/sites/sitename/pun/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List%20Name')/items?$select=Title,LikesCount,LikedBy/Title&$expand=LikedBy
```

Comment: Did you enable **Rating Setting**?

Comment: yeah its working :)

Comment: in the result json, likedby is an object and not an array. Not sure how to fetch values from them

Comment: I have just tested it. It's array of objects. log result in console and try again

Comment: Thanks. If I want to get both ID and Title of likedBy should i used LikedBy/Title,LikedBy/ID&$expand=LikedBy ?